# After deploying Cloud function, but getting some error

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions, twilio

I am new to Cloud Functions, basically I am trying to call the function in react-native app to send the verification sms using twilio service. But when I call function it worked perfectly (sms sent successfully) but on Console I am getting this kind of error:

```
{"severity":"WARNING","message":"Request has invalid method. GET"}
{"severity":"ERROR","message":"Invalid request, unable to process."}
```

This is [my cloud function code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILFYW.png)  and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1AZx.png) is code calling the function from my react-native app.

Comment: Can you share more details of how you defined your Google Cloud Function please? Maybe you defined it as a `POST` method? Then you would need to invoke it via `POST` or change it to a `GET` method.

Comment: ya thank you i got my problem solved basically i was trying to send multiple argument and accessing that on frontend directly which is not possible so then i just pass argument as an object which work correcty

Comment: But now i have a new problem how can i create Custom auth system with firebase authentication to get UID in react-native through cloud function, anything you know about that kindly please help me with that

Comment: Could you please post an answer and accept it providing what solved your main issue ? It  will be helpful for Community Members.

Comment: Regarding the creation of Custom Auth System With Firebase Authentication, please check the following [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth) to achieve that. There are detailed steps provided.

Comment: For future, please do not attach code screenshots and add the code to the post instead. Also please create an another post for new questions to be better tracked and help the Community Members as well.

Comment: yea, I got that , when I read all the documentation it worked , The cloud function accepting one object as argument, and before i was passing a multiple argument which is not even possible that was the main issu, I solved it by passing only one object to a cloud function

Comment: @NibrassH , Okay i will repeat my question clearly and give it answer for a community help. Thank you so much.